# ASP.NET - Set the Line Between every Rows in an GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, sharepoint

I want to set  line between every rows in my **GridView**. My solution is C# Class Library for SP:

This is my code for gridView:

```
SPGridView TableResult = new SPGridView();
TableResult.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
TableResult.Style.Value = " width: 30%; runat:server; text-align: center; background-color:#FAEBD7; margin: 5px 0 10px 0; border: solid 2px #525252; border-collapse:collapse; font-family:Calibri; color: #474747;";
TableResult.AllowSorting = true;
TableResult.Width = 1500;
TableResult.Font.Size = 15;
TableResult.CellPadding = 5;
TableResult.CssClass = "mGrid";
TableResult.PagerTemplate = null;
TableResult.ID = "GridView2";
TableResult.GridLines ........................... ?
```

**More details:**

```
DataView mydataview2 = new DataView(table2);
table2 = mydataview2.ToTable(true, "KmInCity", "KmOutCity", "lKmTotal");
TableResult.DataSource = table2;
TableResult.DataBind();
```

Comment: Have you read [this MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/c31tzf4s)? just a quick googlefu on SPGridView led to that page on MSDN itself.

Comment: myGrid.GridLines = GridLines.Horizontal; with this not working...

Comment: You have a reference to `System.Web.UI.WebControls` and its corresponding dll?

Comment: I'll add more details for my solution in Question..

Comment: is it `myGrid` or `TableResult` according to your edit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112370/discussion-between-gohyu-and-t0mm13b).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321742/grid-lines-are-not-displaying-in-grid-view, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443777/internal-gridlines-in-gridview-in-asp-net,

Comment: Not working... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

.aspx page

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="grid" GridLines="None" runat="server">    
</asp:GridView>
```

Style for gridview

```
       .grid
        {
            width: 855px;
            background-color: #FFF;
            border: solid 1px #525252;
        }
        .grid td
        {
            padding: 2px;
            border: solid 1px #C1C1C1;
            color: #333;            
        }
        .grid th
        {
            padding: 3px;
            color: #FFF;
            background: #424242 url(grd.png) repeat-x top;
            border-left: solid 1px #525252;            
        }
```

If you want to add it programatically, then

```
TableResult.Attributes.Add("class", "grid");
TableResult.Attributes.Add("class", "grid td");
TableResult.Attributes.Add("class", "grid th");
```

Comment: My solution is class library